# Implementation of a program in which characters of a string repeated certain times in haskell

Tags: string, haskell, string-length, non-exhaustive-patterns

This is a question from my homework thus tips would be much likely appreciated.

I am learning *Haskell* this semester and my first assignment requires me to write a function that inputs 2 string (`string1` and  `string2`) and returns a string that is composed of (the repeated) characters of first string `string1`  until a string of same length as `string2` has been created.

I am only allowed to use the *Prelude* function `length`.

For example: take as `string1` `"Key"` and my name `"Ahmed"` as `string2` the function should return `"KeyKe"`.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
    makeString :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
    makeString val (x:xs)
        | val > 0 = x : makeString (val-1) xs
        | otherwise = x:xs
```

Instead of directly giving it two strings i am giving it an integer value (since i can subtitute it for length later on), but this is giving me a runtime-error:

```
*Main> makeString 8 "ahmed"

"ahmed*** Exception: FirstScript.hs: (21,1)-(23,21) : Non-exhaustive patterns in function makeString
```

I think it might have something to do my list running out and becoming an empty list(?).

A little help would be much appreciated.

Comment: just to make sure: you may only use `length` and have to do it all using recursion and pattern matching on the list of characters?

Comment: the error in your code is easily explained: when your second parameter (the list `[a]`) is empty `[]` you cannot match it against `(x:xs)` so you have to include a *case* for it (like `makeString val [] = ...`) in a separate line

Comment: also your `otherwise` case seems strange - why would you return the complete string if your `val` = 0 - don't you want the empty string there instead?

Comment: as an additional tipp: as you see you run out of characters because you *drop*  the `x` from `(x:xs)` - maybe you want to *save* them for later use somewhere (where could this be ... *hint*: you want to somehow give them to the recursive call to `makeString` for *later* use ;) )

Comment: Yes, i am only allowed to use "length" and have to do it all using recursion and pattern matching. And as for your second response, i need to handle such a case separately? Is it possible if i can load my first list again and repeat doing it? Edit: I see what you are trying to say. Thank you! :)

Comment: you cannot *load* the list from somewhere - you have to use what is given to the function - aka it's parameters

Comment: btw: I think you are on the right track to get `makeString` to *repeat*  the characters, you just have to figure out the details I mentioned

Comment: Are you allowed to use `let` or `where`?

Comment: @AhmedZaidi in case you don't have any more questions you should probably either answer it yourself or close/delete the question - just to keep the Haskell tag tidy ;)

Comment: @Zeta yes i am allowed to use `where` but not let. We havent gotten that far in class.

Comment: @CarstenKönig i was actually thinking the same but since i am new to this site, i am still exploring all the features. Cant seem to find how to make a question from "unanswered" to "answered".

Comment: @AhmedZaidi: You probably want to read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code is enough to solve your problem:

```
extend :: String -> String -> String
extend src dst = extend' src src (length dst)
    where
        extend' :: String -> String -> Int -> String
        extend' _ _ 0 = []
        extend' [] src size = extend' src src size
        extend' (x:xs) src size  = x : extend' xs src (size - 1)
```

The `extend'` function will cycle the first string until is is consumed then will begin to consume it again.

You can also make it using `take` and `cycle` like functions:

```
repeatString :: String -> String
repeatString x = x ++ repeatString x

firstN :: Int -> String -> String
firstN 0 _ = []
firstN n (x:xs) = x : firstN ( n - 1 ) xs

extend :: String -> String -> String
extend src dst = firstN (length dst) (repeatString src)
```

or a more generic version

```
repeatString :: [a] -> [a]
repeatString x = x ++ repeatString x

firstN :: (Num n, Eq n ) => n -> [a] -> [a]
firstN 0 _ = []
firstN n (x:xs) = x : firstN ( n - 1 ) xs

extend :: [a] -> [b] -> [a]
extend _ [] = error "Empty target"
extend [] _ = error "Empty source"
extend src dst = firstN (length dst) (repeatString src)
```

which is capable of taking any type of lists:

```
>extend [1,2,3,4] "foo bar"
[1,2,3,4,1,2,3]
```

Comment: You can drop the second parameter of `extend'`.

Comment: thank you for the help! its a great pointer but i am not allowed to use any other functions other than 'length'

Comment: @Zeta i can but is more explicit what's happen there.

Comment: @AhmedZaidi you are not using any other functions. The first one is just a function which solve ur problem and i'm pretty sure you are allowed to use Haskell syntaxes

Answer (score 1):

Like Carsten said, you should

- handle the case when the list is empty
- push the first element at the end of the list when you drop it.
- return an empty list when n is 0 or lower

For example:

```
makeString :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
makeString _ [] = []    -- makeString 10 "" should return ""
makeString n (x:xs)
    | n > 0 = x:makeString (n-1) (xs++[x])
    | otherwise = []    -- makeString 0 "key" should return ""
```

trying this in ghci :

```
>makeString (length "Ahmed") "Key"
"KeyKe"
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Note: This answer is written in [literate Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Literate_programming). Save it as `Filename.lhs` and try it in GHCi.</sup>

I think that `length` is a [red herring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) in this case. You can solve this solely with recursion and pattern matching, which will even work on *very long lists*. But first things first.

What type should our function have? We're taking two strings, and we will repeat the first string over and over again, which sounds like `String -> String -> String`. However, this "repeat over and over" thing isn't really unique to strings: you can do that with every kind of list, so we pick the following type:

```
> repeatFirst :: [a] -> [b] -> [a]
> repeatFirst as bs = go as bs
```

Ok, so far nothing fancy happened, right? We defined `repeatFirst` in terms of `go`, which is still missing. In `go` we want to exchange the items of `bs` with the corresponding items of `as`, so we already know a base case, namely what should happen if `bs` is empty:

```
>    where go  _     []     = []
```

What if `bs` isn't empty? In this case we want to use the right item from `as`. So we should traverse both at the same time:

```
>          go (x:xs) (_:ys) = x : go xs ys
```

We're currently handling the following cases: empty second argument list, and non-empty lists. We still need to handle the empty first argument list:

```
>          go []     ys     =
```

What should happen in this case? Well, we need to start again with `as`. And indeed, this works:

```
>                              go as ys
```

Here's everything again at a single place:

```
repeatFirst :: [a] -> [b] -> [a]
repeatFirst as bs = go as bs
   where go  _     []     = []
         go (x:xs) (_:ys) = x : go xs ys
         go []     ys     =     go as ys
```

Note that you could use `cycle`, `zipWith` and `const` instead if you didn't have constraints:

```
repeatFirst :: [a] -> [b] -> [a]
repeatFirst = zipWith const . cycle
```

But that's probably for another question.